# How to output themekit config in liquid for Buy buttons

Tags: shopify

I can't seem to figure out how to setup an api key in the config to output in a liquid file.

I am trying to use buy buttons, initialising a client like this.

```
var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
    domain: 'shopurl.myshopify.com',
    storefrontAccessToken: 'hardcodedapikeyhere',
});
```

When I do it like this it works perfectly. But I don't want to store the api key in my .liquid file. It should be stored in the config.yaml or somewhere else that's not included in git.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If I have to I will just make it a theme setting. But that doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Comment: Are the buy buttons are using on the Shopify frontend? or on another platform like WordPress, Laravel?

Comment: @Onkar they are on the Shopify front end. The client wants it because it has a separate cart and is used for something different than their normal shop.

Comment: there is no way to hide the store frontend access tokens, JS is client-side and it exposed to frontend users, someone with advanced knowledge can find these very easily.

Comment: @Onkar thank you. Yes my concern is not about showing is it to the front end. Our theme is used in different environments. We have a store setup to run on our local machine, another for a staging environment  where we show the client changes. Then another for the live environment. How can we change the api key for each environment?

Comment: @AntonyThompson Could you write the liquid file as part of your build process? Put your keys for different environments in your config file and then use that to generate the liquid code at build.

Comment: I think then you can use the theme default settings json to create options on theme level

Comment: @Onkar yeah I think this is what I’ll do. Thank you